# How to convert python program to executable [ Python 3.4.2 ]

Tags: python, python-3.x, executable, py2exe

I'm wanting to convert a python 3.4.2 program into an executable file. I've tried using PyInstaller and Py2exe, But neither is being ported to the python 3.4.2 suite.

Do I have any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution from an online forum, [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) is cross-platform and does the same, as that of PyInstaller and it also supports Python 3.4

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Python Launcher for Windows`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) (new in 3.3).

> The Python launcher for Windows is a utility which aids in the location and execution of different Python versions. It allows scripts (or the command-line) to indicate a preference for a specific Python version, and will locate and execute that version.

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants a stand-alone executable, i.e., a way to distribute a Python script without requiring users to install Python. I don't believe this answers the question.